# Notice in Log file: Use of undefined constant REQ - filling up log files

Tags: ee2, error, core

On several of my EE2.6.1 websites I am noticing that the log files are getting bloated with the following notice over and over again:

`ERROR - 2013-08-26 13:10:20 --> Severity: Notice  --> Use of undefined constant REQ - assumed 'REQ' /home/highland/public_html/system/expressionengine/libraries/Core.php 48`

Is anyone else getting this in their logs? Have any idea how I can fix this or what it means?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing anything strange on that site? Does it happen on other sites? Does it happen on every single request, or only in certain situations?

Comment: I don't think anything I'm doing is strange on this site. It is happening on a couple other EE sites that I've checked on, as well. It is happening on every front-end request, not at all from CP requests. I created a new blank template, and went through disabling ALL add-ons and testing, and the log message still shows up.

Comment: I just set up an unchanged, basic installation of EE 2.6.1, and then set log_threshold to 1, and visited my site index page and the log message STILL comes up! If NO ONE else is seeing this, I'd suspect it's my local server XAMPP environment... however, it's happening on a live linux server as well...

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but I turned log_threshold to 5, and the above error shows up first, before this output in the log file:
`DEBUG - 2013-08-27 10:59:02 --> Config Class Initialized`

Comment: Oh, the 2nd time I loaded it, the error showed up further down in the log, between "Controller Class Initialized" and "Database Driver Class Initialized"  `DEBUG - 2013-08-27 11:01:07 --> Controller Class Initialized
ERROR - 2013-08-27 11:01:07 --> Severity: Notice  --> Use of undefined constant REQ - assumed 'REQ' /chroot/home/paleosun/devcds.paleosun.com/html/system/expressionengine/libraries/Core.php 48
DEBUG - 2013-08-27 11:01:07 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an EE bug to me, I'd report it to EllisLab.

The error you are seeing comes from system/expressionengine/libraries/Core.php, on this line in the constructor:

```
@set_time_limit((REQ == 'CP') ? 300 : 90);
```

However, REQ isn't actually defined until the bootrap() method a bit further down:

```
public function bootstrap()
{
    // Define the request type
    // Note: admin.php defines REQ=CP
    if ( ! defined('REQ'))
    {
        define('REQ', ((ee()->input->get_post('ACT') !== FALSE) ? 'ACTION' : 'PAGE')); 
    }
```

So unless I'm missing something obvious, it seems correct to throw an error for accessing a constant before it has been defined. If this is a bug though, I'm surprised more people aren't reporting it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Adrian. I feel a little less crazy. I reported it as a bug here: [link](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19672)